# Convert date (yyyy-mm-dd) to MM-YYYY in SQL

Tags: sql, vertica

I would like to convert a date in `yyyy-mm-dd` (Date format, length 10) to `mm-yy` format.

I have so far tried "right", "Left" and "convert" functions to no avail.

What's the exact syntax I need to use?

```
SELECT
LEFT (day,7) as 'YYYYMM'
FROM bi_core.fact_campaign_device_stats_daily
WHERE DAY = '2019-07-01'
```

> ```
> SQL Error [3457] [42883]: [Vertica][VJDBC](3457) ERROR: Function LEFT(date, int) does not exist, or permission is denied for LEFT(date, int)
> ```

Comment: This question is difficult to answer without knowing the specific DBMS you're using, as functionality and syntax varies between them. Please read the description of the  [tag:sql] tag, and then [edit] your post to add that DBMS-specific tag. Thanks.

Comment: You are right Ken, I will be more specific next time. Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Vertical, use [`to_char()`](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Formatting/TO_CHAR.htm):

```
SELECT to_char(day, 'MMYY') as mmyy
FROM bi_core.fact_campaign_device_stats_daily
WHERE DAY = '2019-07-01'
```

Comment: Worked like a dream. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For SQL database:

`SELECT FORMAT(day, 'MM-yyyy') AS 'new_format'
FROM bi_core.fact_campaign_device_stats_daily
WHERE DAY = '2019-07-01'`

Answer (score 0):

Or also, to get it numeric:

```
SELECT YEAR("day") * 100 + MONTH("day") AS yearmonth
FROM bi_core.fact_campaign_device_stats_daily
WHERE "day" = '2019-07-01'
```